# Wolfram Workbench Installation Stagnation and Should I Divert to IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: workbench, installation

My computer is a Win 10 with MMA 12.3, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2022-03) and JDK 8. My Eclipse works well developing Java programs, and I learned from the [Official Workbench product page](https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/) that MMA Workbench is based on Eclipse. So I thought it would be easy for me to incorporate the Workbench into my current Eclipse IDE platform.

However,an unexpected stagnation occurred when I was installing the Workbench. I followed the [Official Installation Guideline](https://support.wolfram.com/27221): 1.Start Eclipse->2.Select the menu item Help ► Install New Software. ->3.Click the Add button near the top right-hand corner.->4.Enter a name such as “Wolfram Workbench” into the Name field...

But in the fourth step, no matter I filled into the location field http://workbench.wolfram.com/update/  or a directory path like file:/Users/UserName/Downloads/WorkbenchUpdate/ where the extracted WorkbenchUpdate.zip file I downloaded from the [Official Workbench product page](https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/) is saved, the install interface stagnated with no "Wolfram Workbench Core" popping up for me to check and the grey "Next" button staying dead which I can not click to move on.

[image]

[image]

The questions I have about the current situation are:

1. How can I move on with and/or finally finish the installation of Workbench successfully?

2.Should I forget about the Workbench and try the IntelliJ IDE for Wolfram Language? I heard it from one of my friends, who strongly recommended the IntelliJ IDE and described Workbench as "garbage" from his lousy experience using it. Although I have read the  [product page of the IntelliJ IDE for Wolfram Language](https://wlplugin.halirutan.de/), I still have no idea how to choose from the two because I have experience of using neither of them. That is why I am willing to seek suggestions here if you have experience on both of them.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: I don't see this problem. I took the opportunity to upgrade to WorkbenchUpdate_10.2.11. I am running Mars2/Mmav12.2.0/Win7-x64/java version "1.8.0_331". Can you run Java programs in your Eclipse IDE? The WWB installer detected a previous version and informed me that an upgrade will be performed.

Comment: @Syed.  Java programs run smoothly in my Eclipse IDE, so I don't get it how it gives me the stagnation when installing WWB.

Comment: I have now installed Eclipse2022-03 as a standalone eclipse installation and used the update page to install the wolfram workbench 10.2.11 without a problem. In the images you have loaded, try using the correct file/addresses starting with `file: ...` or `http: ` instead of what you have there currently. See [this](https://support.wolfram.com/27221) support page for the procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Syed for your suggestion. The prefix before the file/addresses you have seen in my uploaded images is the name of the repository, which is just what have been set in the official procedure . In the support page you posted, the name of the repository has been set as  "Wolfram Workbench", so you can see there is a same prefix at the beginning. And unfortunately, I tried to  omit the name and let the fire/addresses go first as you advised, but the problem is still there. It is  not the prefix to blame seemingly.

Comment: As the user, do you have write permissions in your `eclipse` installation folder? Just for verification, can you install pydev (or another perspective) for instance to the same eclipse installation?

Comment: @Syed. That is of no question, I am the only user and the administrator by default of my computer.

Comment: Wolfram Workbench does not support the current Paclet format and deployment system (see [my post on Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2561946)). I tried hard to work around this (e.g., see [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2708220) on how to set up larger packages as Paclets), but as of now I must say that Workbench is a dead end for developing Wolfram Language code. Obviously, we are supposed to further be locked-in the Notebook front end, which will never replace the convenience of a fully integrated IDE.